# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type */*

Tags: java, resteasy

I am trying to add a client to use my rest service

```
client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(host+":"+port+service+"usuarios/usuarioNombre/"+username);
        Response response = target.request().get();//  .post(Entity.entity("", "application/xml"));

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }
        System.out.println("usuario ");
        Usuario usuario= new Usuario();
        usuario =  response.readEntity(Usuario.class);
```

I keep geeting this error

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type */* and type class ec.com.mapachedev.webmapper.model.Usuario
```

This is my rest service

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("usuarioNombre/{username}")
public Response getUsuarioPorUsername(@PathParam("username") String username) {
    Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.buscarPorUsuario(username);
    return Response.status(200).entity(usuario).build(); 
}
```

I added resteasy-jackson-provider and resteasy-jettison-provider to my pom.xml but I keep getting that error.

Should I add ec.com.mapachedev.webmapper.model.Usuario to @Produces

I added @XmlRootElement on my Usuario class

[image]

Comment: It seam that your rest is returning the content type */* for which Resteasy can't find a Reader.

Comment: But is it sending content type header saying that it's XML? Check with rest client too

Comment: @ReneM. I add the response as you can see it is an applicaction/xml type

Comment: @JuanDiego Hey! Were you able to resolve this issue?